# jQuery automatically trigger keypress events on page load

Tags: jquery, eventtrigger

I want to simulate the user pressing keys on page load, for example <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>. Using trigger I was not able do that. Also searched on Google but did not get any answers.

Comment: If you mean that you want someones keyboard to press SHIFT R automatically, that is not possible.

Comment: why pressing someones keyboard? hahaaha. I meant to trigger a jquery event that will work like keypressing SHIFT+R on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is described in [jQuery Event object documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/):

```js
var e = jQuery.Event( "keypress", { shiftKey: true, keyCode: 82 } );

$(document).on('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 82) {
        console.log("Shift R pressed...");
    }
});

//
//  press SHIFT + R
//
$(document).trigger(e);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Snippet shows no output, looks like `shiftKey: true` needs to be added to `e`

Comment: @PeterB  Right. I forgot that. I'm sorry

Comment: but the console.log showing after pressing those keys.  Is there any way to make it automatically , like on load or document.ready ?

Comment: @SuUbha Yes. It's enough you trigger the event like in the snippet but for your element: **$(document).trigger(e);**. The e value is described in the snippet. Let me know

Comment: yes, working now. Thanks @gaetanoM